# Is the Android SDK available in any Maven public repositories?

Tags: android, maven

I'm working on an Android project using maven. I searched unsuccessfully on the known public repositories. Would appreciate if someone can let me know about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Google search on:

```
android maven
```

turns up everything you need AFAIK, such as [this](http://www.simpligility.com/2010/06/android-artifacts-hit-maven-central/) and [this](http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/).

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at this using [spring-android-and-maven](http://blog.springsource.com/2011/02/09/spring-android-and-maven-part-2/)